# Concatenate the results of two calls to tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to concatenate the results of two calls to `tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header`. I have to do this because I can't have files larger than 25MB on the Juypter Notebook server, so I have to split them in two.

Currently I'm attempting to do this, but it just gives a `tuple`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas
import time

# Data sets
TRAINING1 = "data/tensorflow/matching/xaa"
TRAINING2 = "data/tensorflow/matching/xab"

training_set1 = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=TRAINING1,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32
    )

training_set2 = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=TRAINING2,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32
    )

training_set = training_set1 + training_set2
```

I'm sure this is a fairly simple question, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a different way to do it. Since later on in the script I split up the `data` and `target` parts it was as easy as this:

```
my_x = training_set1.data + training_set2.data
my_y = training_set1.target + training_set2.target
```